# value in dictionary not updated is it expected-python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

hello everyone I am stuck with dictionary logic ,anyone can help me out

I want to  check if value in set is equal to item in list "lll" , if yes Put the new key, value in dictionary  to true else false

here is my code :

```
o={1, 2}
oo=[1,2,4]
lll=[{'permission_id': 1, 'permission_name': 'can_view_test'},\
     {'permission_id': 2, 'permission_name': 'can_edit_test'}, 
     {'permission_id': 4, 'permission_name': 'can_delete_test'}]

new_list=[]
dict_perm_with_true = {}
for  item in lll:
        dict_perm_with_true["permission_id"]=item["permission_id"]
        dict_perm_with_true["permission_name"]=item["permission_name"]
        for  i in o:
            if i ==item.get("permission_id"):
                dict_perm_with_true["InThisRole"]  = True
            else:
                dict_perm_with_true["InThisRole"] = False
        new_list.append(dict_perm_with_true.copy())
print(new_list)
```

the result is :

> [{'permission_id': 1, 'permission_name': 'can_view_test',
> 'InThisRole': False}, {'permission_id': 2, 'permission_name':
> 'can_edit_test', 'InThisRole': True}, {'permission_id': 4,
> 'permission_name': 'can_delete_test', 'InThisRole': False}]

expected result :

> [{'permission_id': 1, 'permission_name': 'can_view_test',
> 'InThisRole': True}, {'permission_id': 2, 'permission_name':
> 'can_edit_test', 'InThisRole': True}, {'permission_id': 4,
> 'permission_name': 'can_delete_test', 'InThisRole': False}]

any help appreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check other way around, if `permission_id` in `o` then `true` else `false`

```
o={1, 2}
oo=[1,2,4]
lll=[{'permission_id': 1, 'permission_name': 'can_view_test'},\
     {'permission_id': 2, 'permission_name': 'can_edit_test'}, 
     {'permission_id': 4, 'permission_name': 'can_delete_test'}]

new_list=[]

for  item in lll:
        dict_perm_with_true = {}
        dict_perm_with_true["permission_id"]=item["permission_id"]
        dict_perm_with_true["permission_name"]=item["permission_name"]
        # check if id in set 
        if item.get("permission_id") in o:
            dict_perm_with_true["InThisRole"]  = True
        else:
            dict_perm_with_true["InThisRole"] = False
        new_list.append(dict_perm_with_true.copy())
print(new_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

The first round of iteration of item in lll will return `'InThisRole': False` because it will always end with `i = 2` because when item is lll, i will be 1 and then 2, obviously setting `dict_perm_with_true["InThisRole"] = False`

Answer (score 0):

In your example you were looping at each value in the "o" set and comparing it with permission_id. Second value did not match permission id so it overrides first conditional which was False, you don't want to set the value while looping on each value in "o" set, just to check if permission id is IN that set.

```
o = {1, 2}
oo = [1, 2, 4]
lll = [
    {'permission_id': 1, 'permission_name': 'can_view_test'},
    {'permission_id': 2, 'permission_name': 'can_edit_test'}, 
    {'permission_id': 4, 'permission_name': 'can_delete_test'}
]
new_list = []
dict_perm_with_true = {}
for item in lll:
    dict_perm_with_true["permission_id"] = item["permission_id"]
    dict_perm_with_true["permission_name"] = item["permission_name"]
    if item.get("permission_id") in o:
        dict_perm_with_true["InThisRole"] = True
    else:
        dict_perm_with_true["InThisRole"] = False
    new_list.append(dict_perm_with_true.copy())

print(new_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

> In Python, if we want to check that element is
> present or not in string, list, dictionary, set, or tuple we can
> directly use **in**. No need to loop through the entire object.

You can just use **in** to look into *o*. No need to use a *loop* or *get()* method.

```
o={1, 2}
oo=[1,2,4]

lll=[{'permission_id': 1, 'permission_name': 'can_view_test'},\
     {'permission_id': 2, 'permission_name': 'can_edit_test'}, 
     {'permission_id': 4, 'permission_name': 'can_delete_test'}]

new_list=[]
dict_perm_with_true = {}
for  item in lll:
        dict_perm_with_true["permission_id"]=item["permission_id"]
        dict_perm_with_true["permission_name"]=item["permission_name"]

        if item["permission_id"] in o:
            dict_perm_with_true["InThisRole"]  = True
        else:
            dict_perm_with_true["InThisRole"] = False

        new_list.append(dict_perm_with_true.copy())
        

print(new_list)
```